# Making typescript throw compile time error if circular dependency is present?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Is there a way for typescript compiler to throw an error if someone introduced a circular dependency in the code?
What I want to setup is that code throws an error while compiling if there is any circular dependency or a git a commit hook which does the same so circular dependencies are never pushed to repo .

Comment: Are you referring to circular imports? Or circular types?

Comment: circular imports